# What's the relation and difference between a linear mapping and a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

According to a definition that I have a map $L: V \rightarrow W$ (where $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces) is linear if two conditions are met

1. $L(v_1, v_2) = L(v_1) + L(v_2)$, for $v_1, v_2 \in V$
2. $L(k \cdot v_1) = k L(v_1)$, for $v_1 \in V$.

Instead a vector space $V$ is a set of objects, s.t. any two objects can be added together and the resulting object is in $V$ and any object from $V$ can be multipled by a scalar $k$ and the resulting object is still in $V$. Then it seems that a few other [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) are also met.

So, my question is, what's the relation between linear mapping and vector space? What's the difference? How one is related to another? And how not to swap the two definitions?

I had already had a course on linear algebra and we had talked about these topics. Now, after one year, I am confused because I forgot most of the concepts. I think I understand roughly what's a linear mapping and a vector space, but I'm still confused.

A linear mapping seems to be a function from one vector space to another. So, it seems that a linear mapping does not exist if we don't have vector spaces.

Maybe I'm just tired or asking stupid questions, or both.

Answer (score 0):

You're right: a linear mapping is a function between two vector spaces that preserves the natural properties of these sets, namely the following:

- $f(v+w)=f(v)+f(w),\forall v,w \in V$
- $f(kv)=kf(v), \forall v \in V, \forall k \in K$ (being $K$ the field the scalars belong to)

Seen the definition it's clear you can't have linear functions without vector spaces!

Comment: small typo i fixed.

Answer (score 0):

A  linear mapping is not a vector space. It is a type of function. A function from $A$ to $B$ is any  $f\subset A\times B$ such that $\forall x\in A\;\exists \;!\; y\in B\;((x,y)\in f).$

A vector space  over a field $F$ is actually $$(V,+_V,0_V, F,+_F,\times_F,0_F,1_F, \times_{F,V})$$ where $V$ is a commutative group under the operation $ +_V,$ with identity $0_V$... and $F$ is a field under the operations $+_F ,\times_x,$ with additive identity $0_F$   and mult. identity  $1_F$... and $\times_{F,V}$ is the operation of multiplying a member of $V$ by a member of $F,$ with the usual conditions applying to $\times_{F,V}.$

This notation is cumbersome to adhere to all of the time, so we abbreviate with the customary "abuse of notation" , writing $0$ for both $0_F ,0_V,$ and $+$ for both $+_F$ and $+_V,$ and writing $\times$ for both $\times_F$ and $\times_{F,V}.$ And we say "the vector space $V$" or "the vector space $V$ over $F$" instead of "the vector space $(V,+_V,...etc)$".

On the other hand,when $V_1$ and $V_2$ are vector spaces over the same field $F$, the set $S$ of ALL linear functions from $V_1$ to $V_2$ can be considered to be a vector space over $V,$ by defining $(aL+L')(x)=a L(x)+L'(x)$ for $a\in F,$ for $L,L'\in S$, and for $x\in V.$

Comment: With more notational abuse.But who wants to write $(aL+_{V_1}L')(x)=aL(x)+_{V_2}L'(x)$ ?